# IndexError: too many indices for array for numpy in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to calculate a mean from values imported from a text file. After carrying out this syntax:

```
vragenlijst_data= np.genfromtxt('antwoorden.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=('geslacht', 'leeftijd', 'stelling1', 'doorvraag1', 'stelling2', 'stelling3', 'doorvraag3', 'opmerking'))
```

I get the following data:

```
[("['vrouw'", 43, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 
'onbeantwoord'", " '']")
 ("['vrouw'", 34, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']")
 ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']")
 ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']")
 ("['vrouw'", 43, " '3'", " 'sport'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']")
 ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']")]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Now I want to calculate the mean of the variable age, but I get the following error and I don't succeed in fixing the error:

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
(path to file) in <module>()
10 print (vragenlijst_data)
11
---> 12 mean = np.mean(vragenlijst_data[0:,1])
13
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? That would be a great help!

Comment: I tried to calculate the mean with: mean = np.mean(vragenlijst_data[0:,1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading in your data as an array of tuples of strings. This is inefficient. I suggest you use a purpose-built library for mixed types, e.g. `pandas`.

However, you can use either a list comprehension or `map` with your current set-up:

```
A = np.array([("['vrouw'", 43, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
              ("['vrouw'", 34, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
              ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
              ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
              ("['vrouw'", 43, " '3'", " 'sport'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']"),
              ("['vrouw'", 32, " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '2'", " '2'", " 'onbeantwoord'", " '']")])

from operator import itemgetter

# list comprehension    
res = np.mean([int(i[1]) for i in A])  # 36.0

# functional approach
res = np.mean(list(map(int, map(itemgetter(1), A))))  # 36.0
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there any way to do it with 'np.mean' from the numpy library?

Comment: @ltK, my solution uses `np.mean`. If you mean in a vectorised way, then given the way you've read the data, no.. You don't have any contiguous memory array to work with.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: how would I read the data in order to have a contiguous memory array?